# Error while debugging Magento Standard.php

Tags: php, magento, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug Magendo 1.9.2.4 `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php`. I am using PhpStorm with Xdebug.

During the debug it shows me an error that it cannot find the class `Abstract` that it's referring to.

Here is the full log:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php on line 28
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php:0

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php on line 28

Call Stack:
    0.0699     193008   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php:0


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Class `Standard` extends from `Abstract` class which is located in different file but in the same folder with `Standard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

You are debugging your code in CLI environment ("PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration). This way you are executing your `C:\xampp\htdocs\vaimo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php` file *directly* in terminal hence the Magento's bootstrap code (class autoloading etc) is not executed and PHP (yes, this error comes from PHP interpreter itself) is unable to find your parent class.

**Solution:** do not debug in CLI mode using "PHP Script" type of config -- debug it via browser *as Web Application* instead with correct type of config. This way normal Magento routine will be in place (autoloading/configs/db connection/etc) -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+Web+Applications+with+Run+Debug+Configurations.

- [All debugging materials](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm)
- [Zero-configuration approach](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) -- when you initiate debugging from the browser using xdebug browser extension or manually setting up cookie/xdebug param.